# Can I stop music on MacBook Pro with TouchBar directly?

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, music, touch-bar

I bought a MacBook Pro with TouchBar and found out that I could not stop the music directly. I have to first tap on the left-pointing arrow on the Touch Bar, and after expanding the menu I finally could tap the stop button.

However, this is quite a lot of work since I stop and start them again at least 10 times a day, which happen every day.

Is there any way to stop the music just one button, much like it is in non-TouchBar MacBook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can choose to always show your media keys on the Touch Bar as follows:

1. Go to **Apple > System Preferences...**
2. Click on the Keyboard preference pane
3. Select the Keyboard tab
4. From the “Touch Bar shows” drop-down menu choose the option “F1, F2, etc. keys”
5. From the “Press Fn key to” drop-down menu choose the option “Show Control Strip”
6. Untick the box “Use F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys on external keyboards”

Now your Touch Bar should always show your media control keys. When you want to see the <kbd>F1</kbd> - <kbd>F12</kbd> keys just hold down the <kbd>fn</kbd> key.

Comment: Thanks. In this way I can no longer access the app-specific commands? I only want the music play/stop button and adjusting the light... but it seems that I only have a choice to either enable/disable completely.

Comment: OK, it seems that on the 'Press Fn key to' menu choose another option named 'Develop Control Strip' and now I can stop it by pressing just Fn.